# Jedit matching html tag plugin

Tags: php, html, jedit

I'm looking for a jedit plugin that match (highlight or other) the open and the close of a html tag (div, table,...), like notepadd++ (view attached image, in green). Is there something that do this? Thanks a lot in advance for suggestion!

Example:

[image]

Comment: Questions asking for a plugin, library or any other off site resource are considered off topic for SO.

Answer (score 0):

The XML plugin does that amongst other things.

Comment: Thanks, but I installed xml plugin but doesn't seems to do what I need. I looked after in the settings too but without solution.

Comment: Sorry, it works but only if the file extension is .html. With .php extension doesn't works.

Comment: I seems if you also install the PHPParser plugin but choose the html parser in Sidekick, then the matching tag highlighting of the XML plugin works also for the HTML in PHP files.

Answer (score 0):

I solved, in the "Buffer options" it must be set the "Edit mode" on "html".
Thanks

Comment: Of course that also works, but you loose the proper highlighting for the PHP code. The way I told you, you get the highlighting and still have the proper PHP highlighting. ;-)

Comment: yes, I already have phpparser plugin. thanks a lot for the reply. now seems to works all